# REST: POST method with payload mutation

Tags: rest, http

We have a microservice that will accept some data from another component, process it, enrich it and return it back to the client. What would be the best tradeoff/fix for this case to map it to REST?

We can't use GET because the incoming RQ is quite complex;
POST raises some doubts because even when the resource is rerutned back it is usually identical to the RQ payload, apart from the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how much the "process it, enrich it" code changes the resource and if the semantics of the resource is altered in the process.

If your operation barely modifies the resource and so it preserve the meaning, you may want to consider a PATCH operation.

If a lot of fields in the original resource get modified but the resource type stays the same after the operation, you could use a PUT operation.

If the operation alters the resource so deeply that it changes its meaning, you probably are creating a new type of (sub)resource, in which case you will want to do a POST on a different/sub resource URI.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly this doesn't really sound like REST to me. Are you really transferring resource states?

To make this more RESTful you might consider:

1. Using `PUT` to create a resource
2. Using `GET` to get the newly created resource.

Since they are kind of different resources (pre and post 'enrichment') you could argue that the `GET` and and `PUT` should happen on different resources, or at least use different media-types.

However, if I were you, I would not use a REST pattern here and just use `POST` and have that request immediately return the enriched response.